# Editor shows file location as git://IndexOrLastCommit/<filepath>. Can't edit it

Tags: git, readonly

I'm using Oxygen to edit my XML files, and using GIT and our proprietary GIT farm. Oxygen normally shows the file location as a path on my local file system. But suddenly the file location of one file became git://IndexOrLastCommit/<filepath> and the file is read-only. How do I get the file back to normal? Need to edit it. It's commited and pushed. Thx

Comment: This is not a Git issue but rather one having to do with your editor. (Git had nothing to do with setting the file name in your editor.) I don't know what the right tags are, but both [tag:git] and [tag:readonly] are not them. Read the pop-up text you get if you hover over either tag.

Answer (score 0):

Turns out I was accidentally opening the staged version of the file (GIT staging, ready to commit). Thus it was read-only. Solved.